# How to do MySQL queries on text with umlauts in Drupal?

Tags: mysql, drupal, view, collation, diacritics

I need to differentiate between nodes starting with 'O' and nodes starting with 'Ö' (o umlaut).

The problem is that since the node table and the title column have utf8_general_ci collation, MYSQL does not treat o and ö umlaut differently and this query returns nodes starting with O AND nodes starting with Ö

SELECT node.nid AS nid
FROM node AS node
WHERE node.status <> 0
AND SUBSTR( node.title, 1, 1 ) = 'O'

Since all Drupal modules use utf8_general_ci collation, I guess changing the collation of the table and entire database is probably not a good idea.

What is a good workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do a comparison using a different collation to the one the columns are using:

```
mysql> SELECT 'foo'='föo' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';
1
mysql> SELECT 'foo'='föo' COLLATE 'utf8_swedish_ci';
0
```

(`o` and `ö` being different letters in the Swedish collation. You could also use `utf8_bin` if you don't want *any* different characters to match, even different cases of the same letter.)

However doing a compare of columns where the collation is not the same as the collation of each column means indexes can't be used. So it may be more efficient simply to `ALTER` the tables to the more-specific collation you want.

Comment: Adding COLLATE to queries fell over with queries with joins so I ended up switching the database, tables and columns to utf8_swedish_ci using a script suggested by the Swedish Users Drupal Group. If anyone is interested it's here: http://www.phoca.cz/documents/38-tools/154-how-to-change-collation-in-database

Comment: While this a fine general MySQL solution, it requires circumventing Drupal's database API, as Drupal 6 currently doesn't support anything other than `utf8_general_ci`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, as you've noticed, Drupal 6 enforces `utf8_general_ci` collation.

However, this is a known issue, and people have been working on allowing the collation to be specified in `settings.php`: [Database default collation is not respected](http://drupal.org/node/772678)

There's [currently a patch](http://drupal.org/files/issues/drupal-DRUPAL-6.collation.90.patch) in that issue ([#90](http://drupal.org/node/772678#comment-3327988)) for Drupal 6 in review that adds this ability. Once patched, all you need to do is add:

```
$db_collation = 'utf8_swedish_ci`;
```

to your `settings.php` file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the patch. Will give it a spin.